# App Transport Security blocks https post request body data though it's allowed

Tags: ionic-framework, https, xamarin.ios, app-transport-security

I am using ionic v1 to build ios app.
whenever I am sending any https post request, the data is not going and I am getting an error response with data as null

```
{
    "data": null,
    "status": -1,
    "config": {
        "method": "POST",
        "transformRequest": [null],
        "transformResponse": [null],
        "dataType": "json",
        "url": "https://Demo.xxxxxxxxx.com/route1/route2",
        "data": {
            "user": "Demo"
        },
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
        }
    },
    "statusText": ""
}
```

The http request I am doing is

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "https://Demo.xxxxxxxxx.com/route1/route2";,
    data: {
        user: 'demo'
    }
})
```

I am adding this to my .list file

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Status -1 could mean a few things. Hard to tell without more info. For instance, are there server logs? I’ve gotten it for CORS issues. Is this in browser or on device?

Comment: Hi Jackson, I used the same code for android build from ionic and in web also it is working fine. but I am getting this issue when I am trying to check this for ios build. 
I am sending one post request from simulator. but in server the request.body is null.

Comment: You have to show your ionic code for http.post()

Comment: $http({
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: "https://Demo.xxxxxxxxx.com/route1/route2",
                data: {user: 'demo'}
            })

Comment: Do you have access to a Mac?  There is a command you can run to check a url for ATS compliance.

Comment: Yup I was running all these on mac only